# How to change the input border color of postal code field on custom error function in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a project where I have added a function to check the Pincode availability but the problem is on submitting the wrong postal code the input field border is showing green in the color I want to make it red. Does anyone knows how to do that. This is what I have used in my code.

```
function action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation( $data, $error ) {        
    // The accepted delivery zones
    $del_zones_array = array( 000101, 000102, 000103 );
    $data['shipping_postcode']['class'] = array('form-control');
    // If the postal is not within the array, deny checkout
    
    if(!empty($data['ship_to_different_address'])){
        
        if( ! in_array( $data['shipping_postcode'], $del_zones_array ) ) {
            
            $error->add( 'validation', 'The Pincode you provided is not available for shipping online deliveries.' );
        }
        
    }
    if( ! in_array( $data['billing_postcode'], $del_zones_array ) ) {
        
        $error->add( 'validation', 'The Pincode you provided is not available for billing online deliveries.' );
        
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'action_woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 10, 2 );
```

Here is the image of my error inputting the wrong Pincode

[image]

But as I mentioned above the input field border-color shows green

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is one class called `woocommerce-validated` added after checkout validation applied. check out the below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_css(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .validate-postcode.woocommerce-validated input{border: 1px solid red;}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_custom_css', 10, 1 );
```